# Are const values re-evaluated in maps and filters

Tags: javascript

Does JavaScript treat:

```
array.filter(x => {
  const test = [1, 2, 3]
  return test.includes(x);
});
```

the same as:

```
const test = [1, 2, 3]
array.filter(x => {
  return test.includes(x);
});
```

or will the `const` cause extra work on each evaluation in the former?

Comment: That would be implementation-dependent; maybe a given runtime could optimise out the `const` in the former case, but if performance matters I'd write the latter rather than hoping for it. Note even though the array is define as a `const`, it _is_ still mutable.

Comment: `const` or not doesn't matter. If have an array literal inside iteration, you've said that you want a new array to be created each iteration. If it's outside the iteration, then it's only once. What the runtime does is an implementation detail. It may very well only create one array if it recognises it as an optimisation. But that's not "how JavaScript" works. That's how a particular runtime works under some circumstances.

Comment: Jon's right. It's unfortunate that engines don't have a set of standardized (guaranteed) optimizations like this. It would make everyone's life easier.

Comment: This: https://jsfiddle.net/uzLbkq5x/ suggests a new const is created each time the function runs.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73294410/are-const-values-re-evaluated-in-maps-and-filters#comment129440916_73294410) @ChrisG That code will always produce the same result in any spec engine, but the question is about how the engine allocates memory rather than language runtime semantics.

Answer (score 1):

With the first, you're declaring an array only once.

With the second, you're declaring an array every time. Memory has to be allocated for each array and then garbage collected.

The first is more efficient.

Note that `const` does not mean the value is constant (except with primitives), `const` means that the variable reference can't change (for example, you can call `.push` on `test` on the inside array, even with `const`, but you can't reassign `test`)

However it is possible that your engine could optimize for this